# how to put an video inside of an image of a tablet

Tags: html, css, image, video, border

I want to have a video that is inside of the image; so the screen of the tablet would be the video. Is there any way of doing this???

[image: Video Background]

Comment: Yes.  There is.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question is too broad to me ...! Please provide some code and mention your exact problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a div for better control, Then you can load the div with a background of the image using css, then play the video in the image (will overwrite the image)

If you only want the video in a portion of the image, adjust accordingly.

```
<style>
#imagediv {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
  position: absolute; 
}
</style>
<div id="imagediv">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image as a `background-image` and then use `position: absolute` to position the video box there. Next time please do some research and try it first before asking here.